# Require a dictionary to contain certain values (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a model for saving user data to a Firestore database and am initializing it with a dictionary. Depending on what fields I want to update, I put those values in the dictionary so that the user model only contains certain fields and will therefore only update those fields in my database. However, I want to somehow require that certain fields are provided in certain use cases.

*** Below example is a very simplified version of what I am trying to do ***
For example: if I am saving a new user, I want to make sure that I include a name, a profile image, and a description. But if I simply want to update a field, then I don't want to require that all those fields are included

I am 99% certain I am attacking this the wrong way, so any help is appreciated.

My Current User Model:

```
struct FirestoreUser {
    var id: String
    var name: String?
    var profileImage: String?

    var dictionary: [String: Any]

    init(dictionary: [String: Any]) {
        self.id = dictionary["id"] as! String
        self.name = dictionary["name"] as? String
        self.profileImage = dictionary["profileImage"] as? String

        self.dictionary = dictionary
    }
}

// MARK: Firestore functions
extension FirestoreUser {
    typealias Handler = ((Error?) -> Void)?
    func saveNewFirestoreUser(then handler: Handler = nil) {
        // make sure all necessary variables are set
        // if they aren't all set, something went wrong
        guard let _ = name, let _ = profileImage else { return }

        let firestore = Firestore.firestore()
        let ref = firestore.collection("users").document(id)

        ref.setData(dictionary) { (error) in
            if let error = error {
                handler?(error)
            }
            handler?(nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Construct struct with optional value and pass nil as the parameter which you don't want to update.
You can use the below extension to convert struct to dictionary later.

```
struct FirestoreUser: Codable {
    var id: String
    var name: String?
    var profileImage: String?
}


extension Encodable {
var dictionary: [String: Any]? {
    guard let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self) else { return nil }
    return (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments)).flatMap { $0 as? [String: Any] }
}
}
```

Use -

```
let test = FirestoreUser(id: "01", name: "Abhinav", profileImage: nil)
print(test.dictionary)
```

Output -

```
["name": Abhinav, "id": 01]
```

Answer (score 0):

In realtime database use **updateChildValues** instead of setValue if you just want to update the child. I believe there's something equivalent in firestore.

**Answer for realtime database:**

**Update**

```
self.ref.child("users/\(user.uid)/username").setValue(username)
```

**Set new data**

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key
let post = ["uid": userID,
            "author": username,
            "title": title,
            "body": body]
let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                    "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]
ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

**Answer for firestore:**

Just read the documentation for firestore, use **updateData** instead of addDocument:

```
let washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").document("DC")

// Set the "capital" field of the city 'DC'
washingtonRef.updateData([
    "capital": true
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error updating document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document successfully updated")
    }
}
```

**Set/Add new data**

```
// Add a new document with a generated id.
var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
ref = db.collection("cities").addDocument(data: [
    "name": "Tokyo",
    "country": "Japan"
]) { err in
    if let err = err {
        print("Error adding document: \(err)")
    } else {
        print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
    }
}
```

So rule of thumb is to only pass in the field that you need to update instead of the whole collection/dictionary.

Comment: I know how to do that. I mean that I basically want to do something that would be equivalent to setting a protocol on a dictionary telling it that it needs to contain certain keys. So when I call firestoreUser.saveNewFirestoreUser() I can be sure that the dictionary I used to initialize firestoreUser with contains all the keys I want it to

Comment: I understand what you are trying to achieve. I don't think there's a way to do it with the same model. And you must use updateData instead of addDocument or setData